# Does the 15:1 rule in multiple linear regression apply at the beginning, or to your final reduced model?

Tags: multiple-regression, lasso, categorical-encoding

I've read that there are recommendations about how many outcome observations you need per predictor variable in multiple linear regression (often 15:1 or 10:1).

I have a dataset with lots of different predictors. I am going to select variables based on theory. But I'm also planning to do a lasso regression to reduce it down to the minimum number of meaningful predictors.

Does the 15:1 ratio apply to outcome observations:variables in this final reduced model (which might have, e.g. 3 predictors included), or does it apply to the initial number of predictor variables you're putting into the model (which might be more like 7)?

Also, for categorical predictors, does each dummy variable count as a separate predictor in this 15:1 recommendation?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do any variable selection at all?

Comment: @Dave because I have a small sample size and a large number of potentially relevant predictors. My sample size is only ~75, which would limit me to 5 predictors according to the 15:1 rule. I'm not sure which 5 variables to include. I was thinking that if I could start out with more than 5, then the Lasso regression could help me figure out the most relevant. I don't know if that's right though.